# Mac Terminal Printing one console.log but not the other

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, console.log, terminal-emulator

In my code, I identify 2 main console.log arguments and it only prints the first one. Not sure what is happening here. How can I fix this to show both console.logs?

```
const osmosis = require('osmosis');
const website = 'https://www.nitrotype.com/team/DOG';

console.log(`Scraping on ${website}`);

const nitro = osmosis.get(website);

const headingLocation = '.well--p well--l_p';

nitro
.find(headingLocation)
.data(function(d){
    console.log(d)
})
```

````
Terminal on Mac: 
[nodemon] 2.0.2
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node scrape.js`
Scraping on https://www.nitrotype.com/team/DOG
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart```
````

Comment: It looks like Osmosis is not finding any matches.

Comment: Jon, I would have thought in that case d would be 'undefined'. I would hazard a guess that Osmisis (or atleast how you're using it) is doing something thats causing the app to crash (hence nodemon shuts it down before reaching the second console.log

Comment: Nodemon generally throws an error though if it reaches a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
nitro
.find(headingLocation)
.set(...) //.data takes from .set ! otherwise it's empty - therefore, the second console does not output anything
.data(function(d){
    console.log(d)
```

Add .set in your code